# Whistle while charging small cell phone power bank

Tags: batteries, charger, sound

I've one of those small batteries used to charge mobile USB devices like cell phones when there's no accessible power outlet around. It's a [Cellularline FREEPSLIM3000 model HY-L-3000](https://www.cellularline.com/xc_en/products/freepower-slim-3000-universal-4616.html).

Last time I tried to charge it, I heard an unusual sound, like a tenuous whistle. I've uploaded a recording [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=14483227558187058388), it's a 12-second audio file file called "powerbank whistle.m4a".
The sound can only be heard while charging the battery, not while discharging.

I tried to measure the peak frequency with my phone and if the app I used is accurate (no idea about that) there are two frequency peaks, one at 8k and one at 16k Hz.

Now, my question is obviously not about what should I do with my battery or whether there is a warranty on this specific product, but what electric component of the device could produce this sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Buck converter**

The power bank takes 5V, and converts that to about 3.7V to charge the internal batteries.  It almost certainly used a buck converter to do that.  You can read more about how they work online, but the important thing is they have some capacitors and inductors inside which have a high frequency current passing through them. Either:

- One of those components has started to vibrate at the frequency of that current, and that creates a noise. Most likely it is an inductor, and   Assuming it didn't always do that, it probably means a part of that component was fixed in place and can now move, which may or may not mean that component is on it's way to failure. Or
- The operating frequency of the buck converter has changed from >20KHz (which is too high to hear) to a lower frequency you can here. In which case there is something wrong with it, and it probably won't last all that long.